# jQuery live and delegation might not work in plugin?

Tags: jquery

```
$.fn.tool = function(sel){
    this.each(function(){
        $this=$(this);
        $this.live('mouseover mouseout',function(e){
            if(e.type=='mouseover')
            {
                $this.find(sel).show();
            }
            else
            {
                $this.find(sel).hide();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I want to show the element when mouse over the element's container. That plugin won't do.

Comment: Just a remark: you should return the jQuery objects I think: `return this.each(...)`. I dont really see why it's not working. Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: @Robin: adding return still won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `.live()` on `$(this)`, which means it is losing the original selector, which it requires.

Since there's no need to assign multiple `.live()` handlers for each individual element, just do this:

```
$.fn.tool = function(sel){
    return this.live('mouseover mouseout',function(e){
        if(e.type=='mouseover') {
            $(this).find(sel).show();
        } else {
            $(this).find(sel).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: cool, that will do, but your code is missing (), $this should be $(this).

Comment: @runrunforest: You're right, I forgot to update that part of the code. Thanks. :o)

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery delegates with plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858425/jquery-delegates-with-plugins)
It might help you.

In your plugin, you dont have to use event delegation, it's up to the one using the plugin.